# Why does a projector being equal to its own central carrier imply that it is in the center of the commutant of its algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, von-neumann-algebras

In a passage in a proof, there is the following sequence of implications which I didn't quite understand: "The projector P in a representation $\pi$ of a Banach $*$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$, is its own central carrier" => "in particular P lies in the center of the commutant" => "and therefore in $\overline{\pi(\mathscr{A})}^S$" (where $\overline{\,\,\,\,}^S $ is the strong operator topology closure).

I am certain that that last step is related with the fact that $\pi(\mathscr{A})'$ is a von Neumann algebra (a result that I didn't know about and that was the subject of a previous question).

I am really bad at understanding representation theory, the majority of its results are enunciated as phrases instead of formal symbolic expressions, and since I don't usually work with representation theory I have to go back to the definition of each term write it out and try to see if I can manipulate those symbolic expressions using those hypothesis to get the result, but I am not accustomed with the usual way specialists in representation theory think about the subject.

Here is the proof in question, it comes from Kadison and Glimm's 1960 paper "UNITARY OPERATORS IN C*-ALGEBRAS": https://msp.org/pjm/1960/10-2/pjm-v10-n2-p12-p.pdf

[image]

The references are just references to definitions of partial isometry and properties of the lowest upper bound of a sequence of projectors that are orthogonal to each other which allows one to go from the central carrier of $P_\alpha$ to each $P_alpha$.

Note: the $B^-$ notation means $\overline{B}^s$ as the very autors point out to in the beginning of the paper.

Comment: What is the meaning of a projector $P$ in the representation $\pi$? Does that mean $P = \pi(x)$ for some self-adjoint projection $x \in A$ or something? Or maybe it means $P$ is a projector in the commutant of $\pi(A)$?

Comment: The representation $\pi$ maps to operators that in turn act on some Hilbert space, therefore that projector is the image of $\pi$ for some element of the algebra $\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: If that’s the definition I’m not sure what is the question here. $P$ is already in the image of $\pi$, that is, $\pi(A)$, per your definition, of course it’s also in the strong closure of $\pi(A)$.

Comment: This is really strange. The sequence of implications sounds really like $P$ is supposed to be in the commutant of $\pi(A)$. Are you sure that’s not the case?

Comment: P is the same as its central carrier of $\pi(\mathcal{A})$, and the central carrier is obtained by taking the intersections of the range of the projectors that are greater than than that original projector and that are in the center of that algebra, the intersection of it with its commutant, and returning the projector into that subspace.

Comment: I’m also a bit confused about the question, but I will add an observation. If you’re confused about how you go from being central in $\pi(A)$ to being central in its commutant, note that $\mathcal{Z}(\pi(A)) = \pi(A) \cap \pi(A)’ \subset \pi(A)’’ \cap \pi(A)’ = \mathcal{Z}(\pi(A)’’) = \mathcal{Z}(\pi(A)’).$ In general, a (concrete) von Neumann algebra shares its center with its commutant.

Comment: And I don't think that the representation is necessarily closed in the weak topology, just its commutant.

Comment: @FelipeDilhoAlves I know what is the definition of central carriers. That doesn’t really answer my question. Regardless, Josh already provided a comment on the last remaining point that seems possible to cause confusion, assuming $P$ is supposed to lie within $\pi(A)$. So I presume my comments and Josh’s comment have together answered your question?

Comment: I don't understand why that second line in @JoshKeneda 's answer is valid, once I do it will be answered.

Comment: @FelipeDilhoAlves That the center of $\pi(A)$ is contained in the center of $\pi(A)’$? If $x$ is in the center of $\pi(A)$, then in particular it commutes with everything in $\pi(A)$, that is, $x \in \pi(A)’$. But $x$ is also in $\pi(A)$, so it must commute with everything in $\pi(A)’$, that is, it is in the center of $\pi(A)’$.

Comment: @JoshKeneda ’s answer is the formula version of what I just said, once you break down every equality in those formulae.

Comment: Yes, that is it, thank you!

Comment: @DavidGao actually, for that last implication to make sense I also would have that $\pi(A)' = \overline{\pi(A)}^s$, and although you and  JoshKeneda  certanly explained that $\pi(A)'$ is a von Neumann algebra, and $\overline{\pi(A)}^s$ is clearly also a von Neumann algebra, but shouldn't $\pi(A)' \supset \overline{\pi(A)}^s$ in general instead of $\pi(A)' = \overline{\pi(A)}^s$.

Comment: @FelipeDilhoAlves I’m confused. What is the “last implication” you’re referring to? If $P$ is in $\pi(A)$ then it is in $\overline{\pi(A)}^s$. This is just simply because you’re taking closure under some topology.

Comment: @FelipeDilhoAlves There’s also no connection between $\pi(A)’$ and $\overline{\pi(A)}^s$. Why should $\pi(A)’ \supset \overline{\pi(A)}^s$? That would mean everything in $\pi(A)$ commutes with everything else in $\pi(A)$, i.e., $\pi(A)$ is commutative. The correct statement should have been $\pi(A)’’ = \overline{\pi(A)}^s$. That is the double commutant theorem.

Comment: @DavidGao I put the referred proof in which this step is used in the main question, this step from going from $\pi(A)'$ to $\overline{\pi(A)}^s$ can be seen in the last two lines of the image, or at least that is  what I understood by that, otherwise the autors could have just used $\pi(A) \subset \overline{\pi(A)}^s$.

Comment: @FelipeDilhoAlves That’s why I asked before whether $P$ is in $\pi(A)$ or $\pi(A)’$, because in the first case there’s no reason whatsoever why the author would need that final step. In the proof you posted, the author’s applying this to $P_a$, which is in $\phi(A)’$, not $\phi(A)$, so the question you previously asked is not what the author is using.

Comment: The statement the author’s using is the following sequence of implications: if $P \in \pi(A)’$ is the same as the central carrier of itself in $\pi(A)’$, then $P$ is in the center of $\pi(A)’$, then $P$ is in $\overline{\pi(A)}^s$. The first implication is just definition. The second is because the center of $\pi(A)’$ commutes with everything in $\pi(A)’$, so in particular the center of $\pi(A)’$ is contained in $\pi(A)’’$. By double commutant theorem, $\pi(A)’’ = \overline{\pi(A)}^s$, so $P \in \overline{\pi(A)}^s$.